# Call a function inside the same function ( async )

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback

I am working with async-await function and i need to call the same function after some process.

The idea is, for example, i have a table with Parent-child relation and i need to display in order all parent and him children. but with unknown level depth

```
Fruit > Red > Cherry > europ cherry 
Fruit > Red > Cherry > japan cherry 
Fruit > yellow> banana > ... > ....
Fruit > green> light green> apple > ... > ... 
Fruit > green> dark green> apple > ... > ...
```

and i need to get:

```
Fruit
_RED
__Cherry
___Europe Cherry
___Japan Cherry
_Yellow
__Banana
_Green
__Light green
___Apple
____...
_____...
```

thanks for your help.

```
const getChildren = async parent => {
    const children = await Title_Title.findAll({
      // include: [{ model: Title }],
      where: { parentId: parent }
    }).map(plain)

    if (children.length) {
      return children.forEach(child => {
        return getChildren (child.childId)
      })
    }
  }
```

It gives me Error promise

Answer (score 1):

`Array.prototype.forEach()` doesn’t return anything. You’re probably looking for `Array.prototype.map()` there. Also, when you specify a function as `async`, you’re saying it returns a `Promise`. You will need to `await` or use `.then()` on wherever you are calling `getChildren` from, potentially including the nested call inside the function itself. Though for performance reasons you may actually want to do something more like `await Promise.all(children.map(child => getChildren(child.childId)))` in the nested call.

Edit: there may also be issues since, if there are no children, your function returns undefined. I’d suggest removing the `if (children.length)` and just let it resolve to an empty array if there are no children.

Comment: Note that with the arbitrary and unknown a priori levels of nesting, it will take a little more doing to get every single asynchronous call to run in parallel - what I’m suggesting will cause sibling nodes to run in parallel with each other, but not parents and children. It’s possible in principle but if performance isn’t causing issues, I wouldn’t worry about adding that overhead.